# Deploy server binaries on google cloud

Tags: go, gcloud, binaries, gitea

I have a server binary ([gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)) which I am trying to deploy on google cloud App Engine. I can run it successfully on the google cloud console,  checked it using web viewer provided in the console. I have few doubts regarding the deployment on google cloud, which I am listing down here.

> Is there any difference between running a server in console versus deploying it?
>   If there is a difference how can I deploy the binaries on google cloud App Engine?

Comment: I think you need the sources to deploy on app engine. Not the binary.
If you want to deploy a binary, you’ll need Google GCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not as simple as plonking a binary on a VM. Not because this approach doesn't work but because you want to consider security (access|control) and maintainability too.

I recommend you spend some time reading Google's documentation and continue to learn-by-doing to familiar yourself with Cloud Platform.

Some pointers:

- There are multiple compute services for you to [choose between](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview/cloud-platform-services#computing-hosting) on Google Cloud Platform (Cloud Shell, App Engine [standard or flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute), [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes), [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run), [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) etc.). Each, mostly (!) addresses a well-defined use-case.
- App Engine has 2 flavors: standard and flexible. Using Flexible, you may deploy a container containing your gitea binary. But, you will need to use a  container (and I believe gitea provides one) that includes the binary. See [custom runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).
- Cloud Shell is a Compute Engine VM but it's intended as more of a development tool. Yes, you can run binaries on it and yes you can access these remotely but this is likely not the best solution for you in this case.
- Alternatively, (but still containerized) you may also be interested to review Cloud Run, Kubernetes Engine (probably overkill in this case).
- Lastly, you could create a Compute Engine instance (VM) and run the binary on it. This is a valid solution too.